# Example of using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 UserManagerFactory with UseOAuthBearerTokens method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

The ASP.NET Identity 2.0 alpha ships with new middleware to manage getting an instance of the `UserManager` (`app.UseUserManagerFactory` to set this up) and getting an instance of the `DbContext` (`app.UseDbContextFactory` to set this up). There is an example showing how to get this working with an MVC app, but there is no documentation on how to get this working from the SPA template which uses `OAuthBearerTokens`, unlike the sample.

I currently am stuck with:

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new DerivedUserManager(new CustomUserStore(new CustomDbContext()));

OAuthOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new MyApp.Web.Api.Providers.ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

and have no idea how to replace the `UserManagerFactory` above with calls like these from the 2.0 alpha samples while still working with the `OAuthBearerTokens` objects used in the SPA template:

```
        app.UseDbContextFactory(ApplicationDbContext.Create);

        // Configure the UserManager
        app.UseUserManagerFactory(new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>()
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider(),
            Provider = new IdentityFactoryProvider<ApplicationUserManager>()
            {
                OnCreate = ApplicationUserManager.Create
            }
        });
```

Thanks...
-Ben

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am adding stubs here which show you how you can use OAuthBearerTokens... You do not have to use the UserManagerFactory that you were using in SPA. You can switch that to use the PerOWINContext pattern.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

**ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs**

```
public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
{
   if (publicClientId == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
   }
   _publicClientId = publicClientId;
}

public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
   var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

   ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

   if (user == null)
   {
       context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
       return;
   }

   ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

   AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
   AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
   context.Validated(ticket);
   context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity); 
}
```

```
// namespace below needed to enable GetUserManager extension of the OwinContext
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Some New Patterns with ASP.NET Identity 2.0

The ASP.NET Identity includes support for creating a single instance of a the `UserManager` and the identity `DBContext` per application request. To support this pattern use the following extension methods per the `IAppBuilder` object:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserIdentityDbContext>(AppUserIdentityDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
```

You can find a great example implementing this very pattern below:

#### [**ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Cookie & Token Authentication including a sample project.**](http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/03/asp-net-identity-2-0-cookie-token-authentication/)

Here is the AppManager Class:

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUserIdentity>
{
    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUserIdentity> store)
        : base(store) { }

    public static AppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUserIdentity>(context.Get<AppUserIdentityDbContext>()));
        return manager;
    }

}
```

This acticle uses the OWIN Middleware components `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` and `UseCookieAuthentication` to support browser based authentication along with single Owin context IdentityDb Objects and a single AppManager.

#### Setup Bearer Tokens

#### Startup.Auth.cs

```
OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

//This will used the HTTP header: "Authorization" Value: "Bearer 1234123412341234asdfasdfasdfasdf"
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

HostAuthenticationFilter represents an authentication filter that authenticates via OWIN middleware:

#### WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
//This will used the HTTP header: "Authorization" Value: "Bearer 1234123412341234asdfasdfasdfasdf"
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

#### To Generate a Token:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userIdentity.Id));
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
string AccessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
return AccessToken;
```

Comment: thanks, good info here and on your blog. However one thing I noticed: `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();` in `WebApiConfig`has to be removed in my setup, otherwise I don't have access to the token claims and cookie auth gets disabled.

Comment: @BenjaminE. Yes.  That is there to disable Cookie auth while executing methods in the WebApi Controller, defaulting to use the Token Auth/validation. Cookie Auth doesn't really pertain to API/Rest request model.

Comment: You can change the "Bearer" string by "OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType" from the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth namespace

Answer (score 5):

Ben, some of these things have changed from the alpha1 to beta1 builds (currently available on the ASP.NET Nightly NuGet Repo at https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds). If you upgrade to the latest beta bits, you will not be using this syntax anymore but this instead:

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationIdentityContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Also, notice that `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>` is now moved to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`.

You can install the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples' package (preferably in a new MVC project because it might overwrite files). It helped me learn how they do certain things considering documentation for 2.0 is non-existent at the moment besides a few blog posts (all of which written for the alpha1 builds).

Comment: Hi Vesselin, thanks for the response (which I upvoted). I'll upgrade to the beta ASAP. I wasn't sure where to find the Samples package you mention, but is it the same as the samples here? http://www.asp.net/identity/samples  If so, those don't setup an OAuthBearerToken server like the SPA template does, so I still am not sure how to wire it together.

Comment: Hi BenjiFB, the samples package I am talking about is actually a NuGet package. Search for "Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples" in the Nightly ASP.NET NuGet Repo.

Comment: Hi Vesselin, I just checked out the updated samples. (Again, thanks for letting me know that they're there!) Unfortunatley, it seems that they don't include an example which uses OAuthBearerTokens...